# SAS Date Range Algorithm Iteration Debug

Tags: date, debugging, sas

I am attempting to finish this program which aims to output a table of date ranges according to the data column called shop_dttm.  There are other factors that need to be satisfied before one observation can be included in a date range. All of the other columns of the data set must be equal for two observations for those observations to be considered in the same date range. Currently, the program gives me all of the date ranges that exist in my dataset; however, it outputs each date range as a one day range. For example, rather than giving me the range 7/1/15 to 7/3/15, it gives me one observation of 7/1/15 to 7/2/15 and another observation of 7/2/15 to 7/3/15. I am looking for a way to get this program to combine these consecutive ranges to get ranges that are longer than one day.

Code:

```
%let indata = WORK.OFFSELL_ZE;
%let location = city_cd;
%let class = shop_car_type_cd;
%let length = lor;
%let shop_dttm = datepart(shop_dttm);
%let chkdate = shop_dttm;
%let arv_dt = arv_dt;
%let numconday = 0;
%let outdata = WORK.shop_date_range_ZE;

proc sort data = &indata nodupkey;
    by &location &class &length &chkdate;
run;

data one;
    set &indata;
    by &location &class &length &chkdate;
    tempdate = lag(&chkdate);
    if (first.&location & first.&class & first.&length) then tempdate=.;
    retain cflag;
    if (first.&location & first.&class & first.&length) then cflag = 1 and consecutive = 0;
    if &chkdate ne tempdate+1 or &location ne lag(&location) or &length ne lag(&length) or &arv_dt ne lag(arv_dt) 
    or &class ne lag(&class) then cflag = cflag +1;
run;

data two(keep = &location &class &length cflag consecutive);
    set one; 
    by &location &class &length cflag;
    retain consecutive;
    if first.cflag then consecutive = 0;
    if last.cflag and consecutive>=&numconday;
    consecutive = consecutive +1;

run;

data three;
    merge one two(in=a);
    by &location &class &length cflag;
    if a;
run;

proc sort data=three;
    by &location &class &length cflag &chkdate;
run;

data four;
    set three;
    by &location &class &length cflag &chkdate;
    retain firstdate;
    if first.cflag then firstdate = &chkdate;
    firstdate = datepart(firstdate);
    lastdate = datepart(lastdate);
    format lastdate firstdate mmddyy10.;
    lastdate = firstdate + consecutive;
    if last.cflag;

run;

proc sort data=four(drop=cflag &chkdate tempdate) out=&outdata;
    by &location &class &length firstdate;
run;

proc sql;
alter table &outdata
    drop Brand_ZE
    add cflag num label = 'cflag' format = BEST.
    add advance_days num label = 'advance_days' format = BEST.
    add range_length num label = 'range_length' format = BEST.
    modify arv_dt date format = mmddyy10.;
update &outdata
    SET advance_days = arv_dt - firstdate;
update &outdata
    SET range_length = consecutive;
update &outdata
    SET cflag = cflag;
alter table &outdata
    drop consecutive;

quit;
```

Data have:

```
 city_cd      shop_car_type_cd         lor          arv_dt        shop_dttm
    atl            bcar                     1          6/1/16          6/1/16
    atl            bcar                     1          6/1/16          6/3/16
    atl            bcar                     1          6/1/16          6/2/16
    atl            ccar                     1          6/1/16          6/4/16
    atl            bcar                     1          6/1/16          6/5/16
    atl            bcar                     1          6/1/16          6/6/16
    atl            bcar                     2          6/2/16          6/7/16
```

Data want:

```
 city_cd   shop_car_type_cd   lor    arv_dt    shop_start  shop_end  consec_days
    atl           bcar          1    6/1/16     6/1/16       6/3/16     3
    atl           bcar          1    6/1/16     6/5/16       6/6/16     2
    atl           bcar          2    6/2/15     6/7/16       6/7/16     0
    atl           ccar          1    6/1616     6/4/2016     6/4/16     0
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming &location &class &length is an unique ID in your OUTDATA dataset we can just calculate min/max/range of the date and output the last row.

```
proc sort data = &indata ;
    by &location &class &length DESCENDING &chkdate ;
run;

data &outdata;
    do until (last.&length);
        set &indata;
        by &location &class &length;
        shop_start = min(shop_start,&chkdate); 
        shop_end   = max(shop_end,&chkdate);
    end;
    consec_days    = shop_end - shop_start + 1;
    format &chkdate shop_start shop_end mmddyy10.;
run;
```